# Eliminar áreas pequeñas en imagen binaria en Python

Tags: python, opencv

Tengo una imagen binaria en la que hay dos objetos de gran área, pero existen otros muchos que son bastante pequeños (motitas). Me gustaría saber cómo podría eliminar dichas motas y quedarme únicamente con los dos objetos que se muestran en la imagen.
[image: Imagen binaria]

Comment: En MATLAB existe la función `bwareafilt`, me gustaría saber también si existe algo similar en skimage o en OpenCV, la verdad que no encuentro nada buscando

Answer (score 2):

Solución a mi problema:

```
nb_components, output, stats, centroids = 
cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(bw, connectivity=8)

sizes = stats[1:, -1]; nb_components = nb_components - 1

min_size = 1000 # Este tamaño es variable, yo he puesto 1000 en mi caso

img2 = np.zeros((output.shape))

for i in range(0, nb_components):
    if sizes[i] >= min_size:
        img2[output == i + 1] = 255`
```

La función `connectedComponentsWithStats` genera cada componente separado de la imagen binaria `bw` con información sobre cada uno de ellos (como el tamaño que tiene cada componente). En el código elimino el fondo, que también es considerado componente `nb_components = nb_components - 1` que es el numero de elementos (componentes) de la imagen.

Después he ido probando tamaños y me he quedado con el 1000 ya que me eliminaba las motas por completo. El bucle lo que hace es quedarme con cada componente si este supera el tamaño mínimo predefinido anteriormente.

Comment: Si pudieras explicar u  poco mejor como es que se soluciono tu problema fuese mejor

Comment: listo @Christian, he estado comprobando si me iba con un array que me daba diferentes umbrales para definir distintas imagenes binarias y funciona perfectamente

Comment: esto si es una buena respuesta +1

Answer (score 1):

Aplica primero 'erosion' luego 'dilation'. o únicamente 'opening'.

Puedes ver los efectos en el sitio oficial de opencv: [Morphological Transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html)

La primera opción va a hacer las manchas blancas más pequeñas hasta el punto que las motas pequeñas van a desaparecer, luego inviertes volviendo las manchas blancas reducidas en manchas más grandes, restaurando el tamaño original, pero las motas pequeñas ya desaparecieron.

'opening' busca manchas negras cercana y las conecta, entonces las manchas pequeñas blancas se van a ver eliminadas pero las grandes no. O por lo menos intuitivamente hablando, de hecho la descripción que ofrece opencv es que 'opening' es lo mismo que 'erosion' seguido de 'dilation'.

De hecho la imagen de muestra en el sitio de opencv para 'opening' muestra prácticamente el mismo ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo el resultado que obtengo con un kernel de tamaño 15x15 es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu respuesta explica muy bien el concepto de la solución, si podrías proporcionar un ejemplo seria muy bueno

Comment: La cosa es que la imagen que muestro proviene ya de un opening, y se quedan dichas manchas residuales. He probado con la función remove_small_objects y no me hace nada, de hecho los métodos morfológicos que he probado no funciona ninguno (igual hay algún parámetro que pongo mal pero no los domino, ya que provengo de MATLAB).

Comment: Puedes usarlo denuevo (aunque tal vez puedas usar uno en vez de dos), solo debes elegir bien el tamaño del kernel, tiene que ser mas o menos del mismo tamaño de las manchas que quieres eliminar.

Comment: **Alternativa**
También puedes tomar la detección de contorno, openCV permite calcular el área para cada contorno, luego pones un condicional que te permita filtrar areas superiores a 'n' pixeles lo que te permitiría obtener las dos áreas más grandes.

Comment: Si resulta útil, la mísma función que ofrece openCV tiente como argumento el número de iteraciones `iterations=2` que quieres aplicar la 'transformación'.

Comment: @Zyder En el caso de MATLAB no estoy muy familiarizado, al menos para procesamiento de imagenes. [bwareaopen](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwareaopen.html) Lo que muestra en esta documentación es que puedes filtrar por areas con `L = labelmatrix(CC);
BW2 = ismember(L, find([S.Area] >= P));`

Por lo que veo con 'Remove objects containing fewer than 50 pixels using bwareaopen function.

`BW2 = bwareaopen(BW, 50);`' explicitamente puedes elegir el tamaño de las 'manchas' que deseas eliminar. por lo que veo el procesamiento por detrás (de función) es el mismo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta @AlfredoMaussa, aunque al final he conseguido realizarlo de otra manera con cv.connectedComponentesWithStats, dejaré el código en la respuesta para que la gente pueda verla. Pero de verdad, toda ayuda se agradece.